# Null data in an entity, but not null, when it is sent. How is it possible?

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate

When I get an entity "Product" in the controller, I have all the null data.

```
@GetMapping("/admin/product/delete")
public ModelAndView showProductDeletePage(
        @RequestParam String productId
){
    Long longId = Long.parseLong(productId);
    Product product = productService.getProductById(longId);

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/admin/product/delete");
    modelAndView.addObject("product", product);

    return modelAndView;
}
```

[image]

But, in the string

```
    modelAndView.addObject("product", product);
```

I send a product to the form.

```
<div class="w3-container">
    <form th:action="@{'/admin/product/delete?productId=' + ${product.getId()}}" method="post">
    <h2>Delete product</h2>
    <p>If you submit, product will be deleted irrevocably</p>

    <div th:text = "${product.getProductName()}" class="w3-panel w3-card-4"><p>w3-card-4</p>
    </div>
        <a href="/" class="w3-button w3-green">Cancel</a>
        <input class="w3-button w3-red" type="submit" value="Delete"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

And, for example, in the strings

```
    <div th:text = "${product.getProductName()}" class="w3-panel w3-card-4"><p>w3-card-4</p>
<form th:action="@{'/admin/product/delete?productId=' + ${product.getId()}}" method="post">
```

my app has not a problem and returns to the screen correctly data.

### How is it possible?

An issue in it, that I cannot use the entity in the other cases. And in general - how is it possible??

Comment: It isn't `null`... You are looking at the proxy (check the strange classname) and not the actual entity instance. If you click through on the `handler` you will eventually get to the actual instance.

Comment: @M.Deinum, if you will commented my question, I will accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate uses proxies for the entities and currently you are looking at the proxy. The proxy itself acts like a `Product` but doesn't contain the actual data. That is present in the `handler`.

If you click through on the `handler` you eventually will get to the actual `Product` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons are:

- You may have different connection strings.
- Your web application is not in running state.
- You have cached data.

Its not possible in the way you are trying to describe the issue, add debugger/breakpoints to narrow down your issue.